# How can OOP be implemented to call an instance method from one class to be stored in an array in another instance method in a different class?

Tags: java, oop, instance-method

To further develop an understanding of my question:

I have a problem that I am working on in my Java textbook where it asks me to write a class named *GroceryList* that represents a list of items to buy from the market, and also another class named *GroceryItemOrder* that represents a request to purchase a particular item in a given quantity (for instance: ***four units of oranges***). Upon further instruction, I am to develop a client that tests and prints the results of all implemented methods.

**Disclaimer:** I am not asking **ANYONE** to do this problem for me. I am only trying to ask for a mentor to clarify how I may implement an instance method from my *GroceryItemOrder* class into my *GroceryList* class upon instruction from my client *GroceryListClient*.

**Code from my *GroceryList* class:**

```
public class GroceryList_test {
    public GroceryList_test() {
        GroceryItemOrder_test[] GroceryList = new GroceryItemOrder_test[10];
    }

    public void add(GroceryItemOrder_test item) {
        GroceryItemOrder_test[] GroceryList = new GroceryItemOrder_test[10];
        GroceryList[1] = item;
        System.out.println(GroceryList[1]);
    }

    /*public double getTotalCost(GroceryItemOrder_test item) {
    }*/
}
```

Under the instance method **add(GroceryItemOrder_test item)**:

- Adds the given item order (as instructed by *GroceryListClient* when accessing the *GroceryItemOrder* class) to this list if the list has fewer than 10 items (*do not worry about this element; I can do this with an **if statement and null exception***).

I want this method to load the item order from the **GroceryItemOrder_test (String name, int quantity, double priceperunit)** into an array dynamically each time I instruct it to do so in the *GroceryListClient* client, which will be accessed later to compute the total cost in the *TotalCost()* instance method below.

**Code from my *GroceryItemOrder* class:**

```
public class GroceryItemOrder_test {
    String itemID;
    int NumberofItems;
    double priceperunit;

    public GroceryItemOrder_test(String name, int quantity, double pricePerUnit) {
        this.itemID = name;
        System.out.println("Item: " + itemID);
        this.NumberofItems = quantity;
        System.out.println("Quantity: " + NumberofItems);
        this.priceperunit = pricePerUnit;
        System.out.println("Price per unit: $" + priceperunit);
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return ((NumberofItems * priceperunit) * 100.0) / 100.0;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    }
 }
```

Under the public class **public GroceryItemOrder_test(String name, int quantity, double pricePerUnit)**:

- Constructs an item order to purchase the item with the given name, in the given quantity, which costs the given price per unit.

I want this method to be loaded into an array in the instance method add(GroceryItemOrder_test item) from the *GroceryList* class.

**Code from my *GroceryListClient* client:**

```
public class GroceryListClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroceryList_test addorder = new GroceryList_test();
        GroceryItemOrder(addorder);
    }
    public static void GroceryItemOrder(GroceryList_test addorder) {
        GroceryItemOrder_test Oranges = new GroceryItemOrder_test("oranges", 3, 2.46);
        System.out.println("Total cost of " + Oranges.itemID + " = $" + Oranges.getCost());
        addorder.add(Oranges);
        System.out.println();
        GroceryItemOrder_test Grapes = new GroceryItemOrder_test("grapes", 15, 0.55);
        System.out.println("Total cost of " + Grapes.itemID + " = $" + Grapes.getCost());
        addorder.add(Grapes);
    }
 }
```

Under the method **GroceryItemOrder(GroceryList_test addorder)**:

```
GroceryItemOrder_test Oranges = new GroceryItemOrder_test("oranges", 3, 2.46);
System.out.println("Total cost of " + Oranges.itemID + " = $" + Oranges.getCost());
addorder.add(Oranges);
```

Specifically the statement **addorder.add(Oranges);**:

This should add the item as an 'object' specified by "item" into an array under the **add(GroceryItemOrder_test item)** method.

These are the conditions in which I cannot figure out how to perform. Please give any help if possible.

DO NOT SUGGEST AN **ArrayList** because I haven't gotten to this yet, and upon further research I think it will not work easily for this purpose.

Comment: The combination of your question title being very unclear and your question body being very long will hinder us from giving you good help.  Is it possible for you to state your problem more succinctly?

Comment: How would you implement instructions from a client program to construct an item (object) from one class and store it in an individual array of 10 objects in a different class? The client would have instructions to create an order of oranges and an order of grapes, then store these items into an array inside the other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your meaning, you want the `GroceryList` to store different `GroceryItemOrder` objects.

You're close to having the solution in your code.  Look here, however:

```
public void add(GroceryItemOrder_test item) {
    GroceryItemOrder_test[] GroceryList = new GroceryItemOrder_test[10];
    GroceryList[1] = item;
    System.out.println(GroceryList[1]);
}
```

If you trace how this works, then each time you enter the `add()` method, a new array will be created with ten empty elements.  You will immediately lose all references to this when the method exits because it will be [out of scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope_within_a_function) and eventually garbage collected.

To get around this, you need to use a variable which stays in scope.  I recommend an instance variable for your `GroceryList` class, like this:

```
public class GroceryList {

    private GroceryItemOrder[] list = null;

    public GroceryList() {
        list = new GroceryItemOrder[10];
    }

    public void add(GroceryItemOrder item) {
        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            if(list[i] == null) {
                list[i] = item;
                System.out.println(item);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in this `add()` method we only look at the already existing and persisting `list` variable, rather than creating a new one.  We loop through it to find an available slot (if there is one), and then perform the rest of your processing.  The `break` statement is necessary so that every item in the list does not get set to the one item you are adding.

Then your `GroceryClient` class can create `GroceryItemOrder` objects as it pleases and use the `add()` method from the `GroceryList` (because it's `public`).

Note that this would indeed be much easier with an `ArrayList`, contrary to what you say in the closing comments of your post.

Comment: I implemented the code, and after adding a System.out.println(list[i]); inside of the for loop but outside of the if statement I am able to see a list of my objects accumulate each time. Thanks very much, I think I can do the rest from here.

Comment: @RylandCline Great!  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks again on showing me the 'break' command. I didn't know I could use it for that purpose. It helps at least for this type of coding.